# Enforcing an audio sampling rate in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio, core-audio

I have an app that is using the RemoteIO Audio Unit to create sounds. However, due to latency and computational issues, the sampling rate of this system cannot be higher than 8 kHz. I use the following line to set the sampling rate.

```
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareSampleRate,propSize,&hwSampleRate)
```

However, on certain runs I get back a sampling rate of 44.1 kHz. In this case, my app appears to not be working since it cannot handle the computations at that sampling rate. What is my best option to enforce the sampling rate to be 8 kHz? Quitting and opening the app again works but makes for bad UX.

Comment: Audio is a shared resource in iOS.  No one app can force the audio configuration, since that may be incompatible with other OS services or apps sharing the audio hardware.  Instead, try using a sample rate converter, audio unit or part of your audio processing.

Answer (score 3):

As hotpaw2 noted, audio is a shared resource on iOS. You can't get exclusive access to the hardware. Calling AudioSessionSetProperty/kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareSampleRate sets the *preferred* hardware sample rate. As you note, you might end up with the hardware running at a different rate, that doesn't mean that your app can't run at 8kHz.

If you configure the RemoteIO format correctly then RemoteIO will perform the output sample rate conversion for you. The hardware will run at 44.1kHz but your application will output at 8kHz.

You can read about various ways to achieve this by searching for "sample rate" in this documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/ConstructingAudioUnitApps/ConstructingAudioUnitApps.html

One option (as discussed in the docs) would be to set up a mixer with the correct output sample rate, then attach your render callback to the input of the mixer.

Comment: Is there a tutorial on getting a mixer unit, audio callback, and RemoteIO working together? Been trying for the last 2 days. Apple's MixerHost crashes on runtime as well. Tried copying the code from there, getting to the point where it seems like things are connected, but on logging the console, it's clear that the callback is being called effectively at a rate of 44100.
    Member Nodes:
     node 1: 'auou' 'rioc' 'appl', instance 0x1f53e150 O  
     node 2: 'aumx' 'mcmx' 'appl', instance 0x20031320 O  
    Input Callbacks:
     {0xa430d, 0x1f53549c} => node   1 bus   0  [2 ch, 16000 Hz]